# how can we check if all milestones are completed on that case

Tags: apex, casemilestone, entitlements

Assume I have 10 `milestones` running on the Case under a single `Entitlement Process`.

- how can we check if all milestones are completed on that case ?
- How can we calculate the Total ElapseTime and show it in the Custom Field on the case layout ? Do I need to used formula field or the trigger logic ?
- I have End-to-end SLA and some SLA within the main SLA. In order to calculate the ElapseTime of the SLA, I only need to consider the main SLA (not other SLA/Sub SLA which are running with main SLA). How can we differentiate those SLA based on Category & SubCategory ? Do I need to write whole logic trigger ?

Any guidance around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can we check if all milestones are completed on that case ?

You could query and check `isCompleted` values

```
SELECT CaseId,
    CompletionDate,
    CreatedDate,
    ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,
    IsCompleted,
    IsDeleted,
    IsViolated,
    MilestoneTypeId,
    MilestoneType.Name, 
    StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone  
WHERE CaseId='<case id>'
```

> How can we calculate the Total ElapseTime and show it in the Custom Field on the case layout ? Do I need to used formula field or the trigger logic ?

You need to trigger an `after update` trigger, when the status is getting completed then fire this query and update that custom field.

```
SELECT SUM(ElapsedTimeInMins) 
From CaseMilestone 
WHERE CaseId = '<case id>' 
and IsCompleted = true
```

> I have End-to-end SLA and some SLA within the main SLA. In order to calculate the ElapseTime of the SLA, I only need to consider the main SLA (not other SLA/Sub SLA which are running with main SLA). How can we differentiate those SLA based on Category & SubCategory ? Do I need to write whole logic trigger ?

Yes, you need to write logic in trigger. To retrieve milestones based on Category and SubCategory use this query:

```
SELECT CaseId, Case.Category__c,
    CompletionDate,
    CreatedDate,
    ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,
    IsCompleted,
    IsDeleted,
    IsViolated,
    MilestoneTypeId,
    MilestoneType.Name, 
    StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone  
WHERE CaseId='<case id>' AND IsCompleted=true 
AND Case.Category__c = '<my category>'
```

Comment: On 1st query response, I agree this will either give me all Milestones attached to the Case with both values Yes/No. So are you suggesting that do I need to programmatically decide in trigger and keep checking if all SLA are completed ? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, better to check from code, specifically, when case status is getting closed/completed

Comment: It make sense to populate that ElapseTime summation only when Case is closed ? or anyway we can do summation for those SLA which are closed and keep checking till all SLA gets closed ?

Comment: it depends on your business requirement, specially reporting requirements when you try to show case handling in Business Hours and not actual hours. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: for 3rd query, I see `the only aggregate expressions use field aliasing` Please modify the query

Comment: you may have missed comma in SELECT clause

Comment: The query I have given it works for me. you can verify at your end

Comment: Added a screen shot now

Comment: Between Category__c and CompletionDate comma is missing