# How to create a Map of Id and Closed in salesforce for the Entitlement?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am looking to create a Map where I want create Map where Boolean value says Case is Closed.

```
Map<Id, Case> caseIdToCase = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, IsClosed FROM Case 
                                                WHERE Id IN ('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY')]);
```

I want to make the sum of all Milestones ElapseTime completed on the case. I dont want to run the query (mentioned in the link: [how can we check if all milestones are completed on that case](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187935/how-can-we-check-if-all-milestones-are-completed-on-that-case/188055#188055) ) for every case without first checking case is closed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This query will give you, summation of `ElapsedTimeInMins` for each caseId where cases are closed and Milestones are completed.

```
List<AggregateResult> lstResult = [SELECT CaseId, SUM(ElapsedTimeInMins) 
                            From CaseMilestone 
                            WHERE CaseId IN:CaseIds
                            AND IsCompleted = true
                            AND Case.isClosed = true
                            GROUP BY CaseId];
```

Though above query will not return map, but you can loop through the query and create a map according to your purpose.

> Create Map where Boolean value says Case is Closed.

```
Map<Id, Boolean> mapCaseClosed = new Map<Id, Boolean>();

Map<Id, Case> caseIdToCase = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, IsClosed 
                                                FROM Case 
                                                WHERE Id IN ('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY')
                                                AND isClosed = true]);

for(Id caseId:caseIdToCase.keySet())
{
    mapCaseClosed.put(caseId, true);
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can create a Map of Id, Boolean ? where Boolean value says Case is Closed

Comment: check my updated answer with the code